# Running sensors I get gpu temp of 72C and fan 0 rpm... bad?

Tags: linux, sensors

Not sure if I should be concerned.  The temp is not considered high.  But it is much higher than anything else.  Also if I play a video the GPU temp is 85C.

And the fan shows 0 rpm.  Never noticed that before.  Not sure if that is a problem?  Putting my hand in there I could feel the air from the fan on the GPU on a card.  Not sure if they are referring to a GPU on the motherboard?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said you've checked that the fan on the GPU actually works, so the "0 RPM" is either a sensor fault or the driver doesn't actually know how to read the fan speed from this particular GPU model. Or perhaps the GPU manufacturer has chosen to use a 2-wire fan in this model, so there'll be no easy way to monitor the fan speed.

Yes, some GPUs tend to run rather hot. But as far as I know, the "high", "crit" and "emerg" set-points are determined automatically by the `nouveau` driver using the information stored in the GPU firmware, so apparently your card is fine up to 95 degrees Celsius. You still have a margin of about ten degrees even when playing videos, so it's OK.

The temperature and fan speed readings in question are produced by the `nouveau`driver which handles only NVidia GPUs, so unless you also have a NVidia GPU on the motherboard, it must be the GPU on the card.

And you have `coretemp` with a large number of cores displayed, which indicates a modern Intel or AMD processor, each of which would normally have an iGPU of the same manufacturer, so having a NVidia GPU on the motherboard is unlikely.